# Rails, def destroy, is not responding with the destroy.js.erb, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails, def destroy, is not responding with the destroy.js.erb

Here is my method:

```
  # DELETE /Groups/1
  # DELETE /Groups/1.xml
  def destroy

    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In the view I have:

```
<a href="/groups/122" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" >Delete</a>
```

However on delete the log shows:

S

```
tarted POST "/groups/128" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Apr 22 22:21:31 -0700 2011
  Processing by GroupsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"J+A2DN87qoigNxw97oK6NWqPQvXt7KAwLMAM7Er/eWM=", "id"=>"128"}
.....
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 372ms
```

The destory.js.erb is never being called. Any ideas why? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, well, a couple of issues here:

first,

```
<a href="/groups/122" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" >Delete</a>
```

this link is not remote, you can see it in the log you provided:

```
Processing by GroupsController#destroy as HTML
```

to make your link submit an ajax request add :remote => true ( the same way you already have :confirm => 'Are you sure?' and :method => :destroy )

second, you should disable layout rendering when responding with javascript.

So, your action might look like:

```
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :template => 'groups/destroy.js.erb', :layout => false }
  end
```

To make it easier, I have added this to my contoller:

```
layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.xhr?? false : 'application' }
```

so that layout won't be rendered if request is of xhr type. Then you could leave you action as it is now and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed **jquery-rails** gem?, also verify that you have:
 **csrf_meta_tag**
 **javascript_include_tag :defaults**
in your layout
P.S seems to be your controller cannot respond to **js** format, you can also try to add
respond_to :html, :js in your controller's class like this:

```
class MyController < ActionController
  respond_to :html, :js
  ....
  def destroy
  ...
  end
end
```

Please let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of native rails helper for delete links it returns sth like

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) 
   { var f = document.createElement('form');
       f.style.display = 'none'; 
       this.parentNode.appendChild(f); 
       f.method = 'POST'; 
       f.action = this.href;
       var m = document.createElement('input'); 
       m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
       m.setAttribute('name', '_method'); 
       m.setAttribute('value', 'delete'); 
       f.appendChild(m);
       var s = document.createElement('input'); 
       s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
       s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); 
       s.setAttribute('value', 'GAsTX1/XJAAoXBxJuE28EPW9jraQd5N39WeeuvakLWA=');
       f.appendChild(s);
       f.submit(); };
       return false;" 
href="/categories/1">Destroy</a>
```